# Implementing Floggy framework in J2ME

Tags: java, configuration, java-me, rms

I  am creating an application with J2ME. for connecting with database I am using `RecordStore`. This is first get all records and traverse through it to search a record. But I have thousands of records and I just need some based on criteria - is there any way to resolve this problem? I do not want to traverse through thousands of records to get ten records.

I have found Floggy framework at http://floggy.sourceforge.net/ I think it will be better but I am not able to find any proper reference to configure it out.

Does anyone know to may I configure Floogy in my J2ME application? I just want a RMS that has criterion like thing,  see my other question: [Database query j2me including criterias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11931780/database-query-j2me-including-criterias)

Error Stack trace:

```
Created dir: /NetBeansProjects/Login_1/build/preverifysrc
Copying 798 files to /NetBeansProjects/Login_1/build/preverifysrc
Created dir: /NetBeansProjects/Login_1/build/preverified
Preverifying 798 file(s) into /NetBeansProjects/Login_1/build/preverified directory.
Error preverifying class net.sourceforge.floggy.persistence.WeaverTask
    java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tools/ant/
Task
/NetBeansProjects/Login_1/nbproject/build-impl.xml:431: Preverification failed with error code 1.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 12 seconds)
```

Answer (score 1):

The introduction article can be found here: http://floggy.sourceforge.net/core-package.html
You can build your project with Ant: http://floggy.sourceforge.net/configuration/ant.html
But there is also an Eclipse plugin: http://floggy.sourceforge.net/configuration/eclipse.html

Comment: The problem root is NoClassDefFoundError. I have found this on Floggy FAQ http://floggy.sourceforge.net/faq.html#no-class-def-found-error

Comment: i have gone through the solutions provided in the link as i am already using cldc 1.1 but i think problem is i could not find `class net.sourceforge.floggy.persistence.WeaverTask` in floogy jar hence it throws exception that this class not found i have downloaded many jars but i am not able to lacte this class in any of the jar

Comment: I found `WeaverTask` at floggy-persistence-1.4.0/lib/floggy-persistence-weaver.jar. But at this Ant sample http://floggy.sourceforge.net/configuration/ant.html the whole floggy lib folder is added to classpath before calling taskdef.

Comment: i am using netbeans and i have already added jars in my classpath thogh the above error is there...

Comment: Can you create your own Ant build file instead of using NetBeans default build? Floggy plugin for NetBeans is not officially supported... http://floggy.sourceforge.net/faq.html#where-is-the-floggyuml-plugin-for-netbeans