# How to open rms and idx files created by midlet

Tags: java-me, rms

I am running a j2me app in pc using kemulator, after closing app some rms and idx files are generated in rms folder of kemulator, now I want to know that how I can read these files to get some important data of this midlet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not read those files directly in any text editor like Notepad. The reason is these datas are written in binary format. To read such values you must use it's appropriate class like RecordStore.

In case of opening such file in Notepad it will show you some junk values which is not in 100% proper readability form.

Comment: yeah, you are right it only show some junk values when opening with notepad.So now what I have to do?should I create a j2me midlet and import these rms file using RecordStore class?I think there are some method like openRecord etc but I dont remember them exactly.Can you give me the specific example for making these rms to readable format?

Comment: @user1439416, have a look at to this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11606698/996493)